# If all three textboxes are empty don't do anything

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement

If all three textboxes are empty don't do anything. However below code shows all three are empty too. But I don't want this.

```
     var textBoxes = new [] {
    new { txb = txtUserName, name = "txtUserName" },
    new { txb = txtPassw, name = "txtPassw" },
    new { txb = txtDatabase , name = "txtDatabase " }
};

var empty = textBoxes.Where(x => x.txb.Text == "").ToList();

if(empty.Any())
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter " + String.Join(" and ", empty.Select(x => x.name)));
}
```

Comment: How can I use for Windows form application in C#.

Comment: Are you looking for IEnumerable.All()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A modification of @MarcinJuraszek's answer:

```
var textBoxes = new [] {
    new { txb = txtUserName, name = "txtUserName" },
    new { txb = txtPassw, name = "txtPassw" },
    new { txb = txtDatabase , name = "txtDatabase " }
};

var empty = textBoxes.Where(x => String.IsWhitespaceOrEmpty(x.txb.Text)).ToList();

if(empty.Any() && empty.Count != textboxes.Length)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter " + String.Join(" and ", empty.Select(x => x.name)));
}
```

I added an additional check to not display the message box if ALL the strings are empty. I also changed the comparison to use IsWhitespaceOrEmpty in case you have a bunch of spaces (which is generally not valid input). You could also use IsNullOrEmpty, which is generally considered better practice than `== "".` Because you are dealing with text boxes (whose strings are never null) you would still be ok using the old comparison, however.

Comment: `if (empty.Any() && !textBoxes.All(x => String.IsWhitespaceOrEmpty(x.txb.Text))) { ... };` works here too :)

Comment: it says string dosent  contain defination for IsWhitespaceOrEmpty

Comment: still getting message if all three are empty

Comment: If you are on an older version of .Net you won't be able to use that, use IsNullOrEmpty instead

Comment: textboxes.Length is obviously 3, what is empty.Count when they are all empty? If it isn't 3, you probably have some kind of text in there... I don't see any mistakes in my code, please let me know if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

```
var textBoxes = new [] {
    new { txb = txtUserName, name = "txtUserName" },
    new { txb = txtPassw, name = "txtPassw" },
    new { txb = txtDatabase , name = "txtDatabase " }
};

var empty = textBoxes.Where(x => x.txb.Text == "").ToList();

if(empty.Any())
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter " + String.Join(" and ", empty.Select(x => x.name)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I dont want to show any message if all the text boxes are empty